# How to enable setting optional boolean field to nil with ExAdmin?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, exadmin

For an Ecto schema that has an optional boolean field, is it possible to set up ExAdmin to allow the user to set the value to `nil`, `true`, or `false`? Out of the box, it seems to only allow setting the value to `true` or `false`.

Here's what the Ecto schema might look like:

```
defmodule ExampleSchema do
  # ...

  schema "example_schema" do
    field :optional_boolean, :boolean
  end

  def changeset(schema, params) do
    schema
    |> cast(params, [:optional_boolean])
    |> validate_required([:optional_boolean])
  end
end
```

And here's what the ExAdmin code looks like:

```
defmodule ExAdmin.ExampleSchema do
  use ExAdmin.Register

  register_resource ExampleSchema do
    form resource do
      inputs do
        input resource, :optional_boolean
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Boolean means two-state, not three-state. If you need a three+ state, use an enum instead.